# Cookie Problem in Python

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I'm working on a simple HTML scraper for Hulu in python 2.6 and am having problems with logging on to my account.  Here's my code so far:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar
#make a cookie and redirect handlers
cookies = CookieJar() 
cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies)
redirect_handler= urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler,cookie_handler)#make opener w/ handlers

#build the url
login_info = {'username':USER,'password':PASS}#USER and PASS are defined
data = urllib.urlencode(login_info)

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.hulu.com/account/authenticate",data)#make the request
test = opener.open(req) #open the page
print test.read() #print html results
```

The code compiles and runs, but all that prints is:

```
Login.onError("Please \074a href=\"/support/login_faq#cant_login\"\076enable cookies\074/a\076 and try again.");
```

I assume there is some error in how I'm handling cookies, but just can't seem to spot it.  I've heard Mechanize is a very useful module for this type of program, but as this seems to be the only speed bump left, I was hoping to find my bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting back could be misleading. For example the server might be looking at *user-agent* and seeing that say it's not one of the supported browsers, or looking at *HTTP_REFERER* expecting it to be coming from hulu domain. My point is there are two many variables coming in the request to keep guessing them one by one

I recommend using an http analyzer tool, e.g. [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or the one in [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to figure out what (header fields, cookies, parameters) the client sends to server when you doing hulu login via a browser. This will give you the **exact** request that you need to construct in your python code.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is a ajax return. It is probably using javascript to set the cookie, and screwing up your attempts to authenticate.